# VSCode is asking to open external website every time I open it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I open Visual Studio Code, the dialogue box shown on the image below comes twice **asking me to open an external website** which is very irritating during work.

[image: IMG:]

Can you please help me how to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed it. Went to the **extension** section and found out which extension of which developer was responsible for this and disabled that. Mine was from **Shan Khan** developer. I found the name easily as it was closer to the link's part "shanalikhan" if you observe. Thank you.